# Using regex fetch the first memory address of filename listings

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text as a response of a script:

```
7d60f000-7d67b000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 11         /bin/busybox.nosuid
7d68b000-7d68c000 r--p 0006c000 fb:00 11         /bin/busybox.nosuid
7d68c000-7d68d000 rw-p 0006d000 fb:00 11         /bin/busybox.nosuid
b3dfb000-b3ebe000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 1636       /lib/libc-2.31.so
b3ebe000-b3ecd000 ---p 000c3000 fb:00 1636       /lib/libc-2.31.so
b3ecd000-b3ecf000 r--p 000c2000 fb:00 1636       /lib/libc-2.31.so
b3ecf000-b3ed1000 rw-p 000c4000 fb:00 1636       /lib/libc-2.31.so
b3ed1000-b3ed3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b3ed3000-b3f24000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 1655       /lib/libm-2.31.so
b3f24000-b3f33000 ---p 00051000 fb:00 1655       /lib/libm-2.31.so
b3f33000-b3f34000 r--p 00050000 fb:00 1655       /lib/libm-2.31.so
b3f34000-b3f35000 rw-p 00051000 fb:00 1655       /lib/libm-2.31.so
b3f35000-b3f36000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 4296       /usr/lib/libcrashlog.so.0.0.0
b3f36000-b3f45000 ---p 00001000 fb:00 4296       /usr/lib/libcrashlog.so.0.0.0
b3f45000-b3f46000 r--p 00000000 fb:00 4296       /usr/lib/libcrashlog.so.0.0.0
b3f46000-b3f47000 rw-p 00001000 fb:00 4296       /usr/lib/libcrashlog.so.0.0.0
b3f47000-b3f5d000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 1628       /lib/ld-2.31.so
b3f6b000-b3f6d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b3f6d000-b3f6e000 r--p 00016000 fb:00 1628       /lib/ld-2.31.so
b3f6e000-b3f6f000 rw-p 00017000 fb:00 1628       /lib/ld-2.31.so
```

I'm trying to fetch the address for each file name, eg:

- for `/bin/busybox.nosuid` return `7d60f000-7d67b000`
- for `/lib/libc-2.31.so` return `b3dfb000-b3ebe000`
- for `/lib/libm-2.31.so` return `b3ed3000-b3f24000`
- for `/usr/lib/libcrashlog.so.0.0.0` return `b3f35000-b3f36000`
- for `/lib/ld-2.31.so` return `b3f47000-b3f5d000`

Can this be done with regex?

Comment: Will this process be one-line at a time, or all lines all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single line, you can use the following pattern to capture the data.

```
^(?i)([a-f\d]{8}-[a-f\d]{8})
```

In Java, you can use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` objects to return captured values.

```java
String string = "7d60f000-7d67b000 r-xp 00000000 fb:00 11         /bin/busybox.nosuid";
String address = null;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?i)([a-f\\d]{8}-[a-f\\d]{8})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) 
    address = matcher.group(1);
```

Output

```
7d60f000-7d67b000
```

Alternatively, if you require all values to be evaluated at once, you can use the following.

```java
Map<String, String> map(String string) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(string));
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String[] strings;
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        strings = line.split(" +", 6);
        if (strings.length > 5) {
            if (!map.containsKey(strings[5]))
                map.put(strings[5], strings[0]);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Output, formatted

```
{/bin/busybox.nosuid=7d60f000-7d67b000, 
 /lib/libc-2.31.so=b3dfb000-b3ebe000, 
 /lib/libm-2.31.so=b3ed3000-b3f24000, 
 /usr/lib/libcrashlog.so.0.0.0=b3f35000-b3f36000, 
 /lib/ld-2.31.so=b3f47000-b3f5d000}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following regex:

```
(^[a-f0-9]{8}\-[a-f0-9]{8})\s[rwxp\-]+\s[a-f0-9]{8}\s[a-f0-9]{2}:[a-f0-9]{2} \d+\s+(\/(?:bin|lib|usr\/lib\/)[^.]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)*)$
```

Your matches will be found in:

- Group 1: hexadecimal code
- Group 2: path

**Regex Explanation**:

- `^`: start of string
- `([a-f0-9]{8}\-[a-f0-9]{8})`: hexadecimal code

  - `[a-f0-9]{8}`: 8 hex characters
  - `\-`: dash
  - `[a-f0-9]{8}`: 8 hex characters
- `\s`: space
- `[rwxp\-]{4}`: linux file permission characters
- `\s`: space
- `[a-f0-9]{8}\s[a-f0-9]{2}:[a-f0-9]{2}\d+`: hexadecimal characters
- `\s+`: spaces
- `(\/(?:bin|lib|usr\/lib\/)[^.]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)*)`: path

  - `\/`: slash
  - `(?:bin|lib|usr\/lib\/)`: one of the linux main folders
  - `[^.]+`: any character except dot (can be substituted with filename possible characters)
  - `(?:\.[^.\s]+)*`: optional sequence of dot and non-dot characters
- `$`: end of string

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/JOJjoc/1).